# how to decrypt a base 64 string?

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, mobile

I'll explain my problem, I'm trying to encrypt a password, then save it locally so that I can go and retrieve it when necessary, decrypt it and assign it wherever I want.
In the encryption phase I do not get any problems in the sense that the encrypt method can easily return a string while in the decrypt method I have problems, because the return type seems to have to be of the Encrypt type.

By doing so it is impossible for me to go and get the string saved locally thanks to sharedPreferences and be able to decrypt it, I am going to give you the code below to better understand my problem:

```
class _State extends State<SettingsPage> {
  static final key = encrypt.Key.fromLength(32);
  static final iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength(16);
  static final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));

  static encryptAES(text) {
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(text, iv: iv);
    return encrypted;
  }

  static decryptAES(text) {
    print(text.base64);
    String decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(text, iv: iv);
    print(decrypted);
    return decrypted;
  }

 SettingsPage.inputPassword = input[0];
                      // SettingsPage.inputPassword = tec.text;
                      encryptedText = encryptAES(SettingsPage.inputPassword).base64;

                      setState(() {
                        String encryptedText =
                            encryptAES(SettingsPage.inputPassword).base64;
                        print("PROVA ENCRYPTED TEXT " + encryptedText);
                      });

                      prefs.setString('savedPass', encryptedText.base64);
                      String decryptedText = decryptAES(encryptedText).base64;
                      print("PROVA TESTO DECRIPTATO " + decryptedText);
                    }
                  },
```

Everything proceeds as required until the password is saved, then I ask you how to decrypt a string in order to be able to assign the variable DecryptedText to the String variable correctly, since at this moment I am told:

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'base64'.
```

This is because it would appear that the decrypted method can only return an Encrypt type.
The pub.dev API used is encrypt: ^5.0.1.
THANKS.

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place?

Comment: I need to decrypt it to be able to use it during login.

Comment: Do you think it's a safe solution? Can't you use some sort of api_token or something?

Comment: why shouldn't it be a safe solution?
I don't know how to do this I ask ...

Comment: To convert a Base64 encoded ciphertext to an `Encrypted` object, simply use [`Encrypted.from64()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypted/Encrypted.from64.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `package:encrypt`, but skimming over the documentation you should be using [`Encrypted.fromBase64`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypted/Encrypted.fromBase64.html) to construct an `Encrypted` object to pass to `Encrypter.decrypt`:

```dart
static String decryptAES(String base64Text) {
  print(base64Text);
  String decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.fromBase64(base64Text), iv: iv);
  print(decrypted);
  return decrypted;
}
```

Note that you also should be calling just `decryptAES(...)`, not `decryptAES(...).base64`. (You want the original text back, not a base64-encoded version.)

```dart
encryptedTextBase64 = encryptAES(SettingsPage.inputPassword).base64;
...
String decryptedText = decryptAES(encryptedTextBase64);
```

I will point out that your code is very hard to follow (which is especially bad for security-related code) because:

1. Your functions do not declare argument types nor return types and therefore take and return `dynamic` types.  This makes it hard to understand what arguments they expect and what they are expected to return.
2. You should name your variables to make it clear what is base64-encoded and what isn't. (I renamed the variables in the example above.)

Comment: this is what i get: The method 'fromBase64' isn't defined for the type 'Encrypter'.

Comment: @SimoneSpagnolo Sorry, that was a typo.  I got the `Encrypter` and `Encrypted` classes mixed up.  I meant `Encrypted.fromBase64`.

Comment: thanks a lot but I always get the same error: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'base64'.
in the application of the code do I have to change anything?

Comment: As shown in my example, you have to remove the `.base64` call wherever you call `decryptAES`.  It doesn't make sense since you're trying to extract the original string, not base64-encode it.

Comment: even removing it always the same mistake ... I can't understand why

Comment: If you're still receiving an error `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'base64'`, you're clearly calling `.base64` on a `String` somewhere.  Stop doing that.  The stack trace will tell you the offending line.

Comment: thanks a lot it works! you have been really helpful 
and patient.